# Power LED keeps Blinking - Asus p52f Laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, power-supply, asus-laptop

I am facing an issue since a long time. I own Asus p52f series laptop, it's 3 years old right now. 2 months back I had to change the laptop battery, since I couldn't find the original Asus laptop battery anywhere, I had to purchase Club Laptop laptop.

I am facing an weird issue since then. The power led of the laptop is keeping on blinking, giving out Yellow - Orange colour. I tried method found online like, removing the battery and re plugging it back into the laptop. It actually worked, but after 5 or 6 hours it keeps blinking again. Now everyday I have to pull out and insert back the battery in order to get rid of this issue and also the laptop cannot compute the total battery capacity/total charge left when this led keeps blinking.

Is there anywhere to get rid of this permanently? NB: I use Mint linux latest version the whole time and I keep the charger pin plugged into the laptop always.

Comment: Sounds like you got a crap battery.  Are you _sure_ the replacement battery's specs are appropriate for your notebook? What is the Voltage ratings on the old and new batteries? If you run off AC-only power does it still blink the LED as you explain?

Comment: According to the manual (link below), the power light flashes orange when the AC cord is not connected and battery is less than 10% charged. If that is not the case then I think Techie007 is correct. The BIOS is not recognizing the battery charge and/or the AC adapter. http://www.manualowl.com/m/Asus/P52F/Manual/262022

Comment: ` I had to purchase Club Laptop laptop.` uhm, what did you buy? A battery or a new laptop?